# Filter cells using cell value as reference

Tags: excel, vba

i need to filter an excel worksheet using a cell value as reference..
Right now what i found was using vba, so this is my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If (Intersect(Target, Range("f2")) Is Nothing) _
   Then
     Exit Sub
   End If

   Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Range("f2").Value

End Sub
```

But everytime i change value of cell f2 it hides all cells and excel crashes, somehow...
So what i need is:
Use cell f2 as reference for criteria, to filter data in range a1:d100, so that when value in cell f2 changes, a1:d100 only shows lines in which the the criteria is true...

field 2 is the description of a product, like a computer, so every time i write in f2 the text "HP", it show only HP computers for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all, but i solved my problem, if anyone is interested here is my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If (Intersect(Target, Range("f1")) Is Nothing) _
   Then
      Exit Sub
   End If
   Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & Range("f1")
   Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & Range("f1") & "*"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Tbl As Range
    Set Tbl = Range("A1:D100")
    If Intersect(Range("F2"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Tbl.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Range("F2").Value
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**  The filter may hide row #2.  This may make it a little difficult to change cell **F2.**